# Install extension of webpimages

Tags: magento2, extensions

I bought the webpimages from marketplace.magento.com and start to install from the instruction:
https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/install/

I insert in the file composer.json in require: {
"jajuma/module-webpimages": "^2.1.8"
}

After that I want to install it via ssh.
but when I insert the command

composer require jajuma/module-webpimages:2.1.8

I will get always the message:

bash: composer: command not found

I tried the different folder but will get always the same message.
Hope someone can help me there.
kindly regards

Comment: How did you install magento? It seems, that "composer" is not installed. You can try to install it and run the command again. 
https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 0):

Either download a composer.phar file from getcomposer.org and use `php composer.phar <command>`, or install composer globally to be able to use `composer <command>`:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

> After running the installer following the Download page instructions
> you can run this to move composer.phar to a directory that is in your
> path:
>
> `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
It seems that I have already installed composer on the server because I can find the files composer.json and composer.phar in my folder.
Here my content of my folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Jul 13  2021 Agoshop
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01  752513 Apr 27  2020 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01     659 Apr 27  2020 COPYING.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    2994 Apr 27  2020 Gruntfile.js.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01   10411 Apr 27  2020 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01   10424 Apr 27  2020 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01     700 Apr 27  2020 SECURITY.md 
drwxr-xr-x  6 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 app
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01     189 Jun 30  2021 auth.json
drwxr-xr-x  2 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01  268613 Apr 27  2020 composer-setup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    2778 Feb 21 14:18 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    2284 Apr 27  2020 composer.json.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01  808528 Aug 12  2021 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01 1909682 Apr 27  2020 composer.phar
drwxr-xr-x  5 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 dev
drwxr-xr-x  3 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Aug 12  2021 generated
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01      57 Apr 27  2020 grunt-config.json.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    1409 Apr 27  2020 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 media
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    5742 Apr 27  2020 nginx.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    1416 Apr 27  2020 package.json.sample
drwxr-xr-x  2 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 phpserver
drwxrwxrwx  6 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 pub
drwxr-xr-x  7 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 setup
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    3658 Jul 13  2021 sitemap2.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4345 Jul 13  2021 sitemap3.xml
drwxr-xr-x  7 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Apr 27  2020 update
drwxrwxrwx 11 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Feb 21 15:12 var
drwxr-xr-x 86 agoshopat01 agoshopat01    4096 Aug 12  2021 vendor
```

Here my content of my file composer.json:

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "use-include-path": true,
    "disable-tls": true
},
"require": {
    "adfix/squarefeed": "^2.0",
    "amasty/gdpr-cookie": "^2.6",
    "iubenda/module-cookiesolution": "^2.4",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.4",
    "magmodules/m2-googleshopping": "^1.2",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^6",
    "sy/slider": "^0.4.2",
    "ulmod/ordercomment": "^2.4",
    "w3ctrl/module-delete-orders": "^1.0",
    "weltpixel/module-google-tag-manager": "^1.10",
    "jajuma/module-webpimages": "^2.1.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.14.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~3.0.0",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.4.5",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.4.0"
},
"conflict": {
    "gene/bluefoot": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"version": "2.3.0",
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}

Hope someone can still help me.
kindly regards

Comment: Judging by this answer, you don't understand how the composer "installation" or usage works. Just try my answer and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your answser:
I have tried the following command:

php composer.phar require jajuma/module-webpimages:2.1.8

After that I will get the following message:

You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a matching version of package jajuma/module-webpimages. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Hope someone can still help me here.
Kindly regards

Comment: I have tried to update to composer 2 with the command:
composer self-update --2

But I will get the following message in any folder:
bash: composer: command not found

Comment: ...you can't use `composer` when you haven't installed globally, as I pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So you mean I must do the Command-line installation from https://getcomposer.org/download/ first?
kindly regards for an further answer

Comment: Yes, that may be easiest. Or you try typing „php composer.phar“ every time a tutorial says „composer“. It is important that you understand the difference between the file that you see in your Magento directory, and the file which is used when you type „composer“, which is a different file in a different directory (see my first answer and the link)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The strange thing is that I have already the file composer-setup.php in my folder and I think it is already installed because I can finde also a composer.phar file. But I cannot start the command "php composer.phar"

Comment: Maybe an issue with php version or Setup of your local machine? What is the error message? Sounds pretty specific. I don’t know if I can help much further. Maybe someone from your workplace who has experience with your setup can help faster

Comment: Hi!
As I wrote. When I use "php composer.phar require jajuma/module-webpimages:2.1.8" I will get an message, that I should upgrade to Composer 2.
When I use php composer.phar self-update --2 I will get:
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--2" option does not exist.
I use php 7.3.33.
Hope someone can still help me here. Kindly regards.